# simplest way to make a python module usable as a cli-tool

Tags: python, module, pip, command-line-interface

I'd like to make a cli tool and found this as a reference: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

So I created a directory with the following structure

```
$ tree modules_and_packages
modules_and_packages
├── bin
│   ├── cli_script
│   └── cli_script~
├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
├── setup.py~
├── some_module.py
└── some_module.py~
```

I can install the module through pip without any problems:

```
pip3 install ./modules_and_packages
Processing ./modules_and_packages
Installing collected packages: some-module
  Running setup.py install for some-module ... done
Successfully installed some-module-0.0.0
```

But when I run `cli_script` on the command line, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/.local/bin/cli_script", line 3, in <module>
    import modules_and_packages
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules_and_packages'
```

Here's what's in the files:

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='some_module',
    py_modules=['some_module'],
    scripts=['bin/cli_script']
)
```

some_module.py

```
def​ some_func():
    return​ 42
```

bin/cli_script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import modules_and_packages
print('hello')
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to test the simplest case for making a command line tool using a module.  What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Error message I get when trying to import some_module after trying hoefling's suggestion

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/some_module.py", line 1
    ​def​ some_func():
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not including `modules_and_packages` in the distribution. This is because your project structure is wrong - compare it with the one in the tutorial you referenced. It should look like the following:

```
myproject
├── modules_and_packages
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_module.py
├── setup.py
└── bin
    └── cli_script
```

Now include the package `modules_and_packages` to the dist in the setup script:

```
# setup.py

setup(
    name='some_module',
    packages=['modules_and_packages'],
    scripts=['bin/cli_script']
)
```

It gets even easier if you use the `setuptools.find_packages()` function for package collection:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='some_module',
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=['bin/cli_script']
)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but I changed the structure as you suggested, and it seems that the correct module is being imported, but I still get the following error message: ``` edit: I'll add the error message to the original question
```

Comment: That's because you have garbage characters hidden in the line, like zero-width spaces and stuff. Copy the line containing the `def some_func():` and print its repr from command line, e.g. `python -c "print(repr('    def some_func():'))"`. This will show the codes of garbage characters you have to delete or replace.

Comment: Most probably you have copied the code from some webpage that appends additional formatting characters that make you code not runnable.

Comment: I thought of that as well, so I typed it out by hand, but it still isn't working.  At any rate, I made a separate question for that.  Thanks for the help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171637/syntaxerror-invalid-character-in-identifier-despite-there-being-almost-certa

Answer (score 3):

The guide you are following is 5 years old and a little vague. You could setup your cli-tool like so:

```
~ tree modules_and_packages
├── bin
│   └── cli_script
├── setup.py
└── some_module
    ├── __init__.py
    └── some_module.py
```

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='some_module',
    py_modules=['some_module'],
    scripts=['bin/cli_script']
)
```

some_module/__init__.py

```py
from .some_module import *
```

some_module/some_module.py

```py
def some_func():
    return 42
```

bin/cli_script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import some_module

print('hello')
print(some_module.some_func())
```

Then to install, in the `modules_and_packages` directory, run:

```sh
~ python setup.py develop
```

Then running:

```sh
~ cli_script
hello
42
```

---

Alternatively, if you are familiar with [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/), I would recommend using [this template](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage) for a python package, as it has a built in cli interface.