# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier -- despite there being almost certainly no unallowed character

Tags: python, syntax-error, character

I'm getting the message:

```
>>> import some_module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/some_module.py", line 1
    ​def​ some_func():
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

When I am trying to import a local module from a package I installed with pip.

The structure of the package is as follows:

```
modules_and_packages
├── modules_and_packages
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_module.py
├── setup.py
└── bin
    └── cli_script
```

The code for some_module.py is as follows:

```
def some_func():
    return 'hello'
```

Other relevant(?) files:

## setup.py

```
setup(
    name='some_module',
    packages=['modules_and_packages'],
    scripts=['bin/cli_script']
)
```

## bin/cli_script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import modules_and_packages
print('hello')
```

Comment: Seems like it could be an invisible character. If you copy the code you posted into `some_module.py`, it might fix it. Otherwise, that's very strange...

Comment: @TomRobinson  That occurred to me too and I already tried this.  Just tried it again to be sure, and I get the same error message.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the output of `pyhon -c 'print(open("/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/some_module.py", 'rb).read())'`?